# Loop not adding data to table

Tags: python, django

The for loop works, but instead of adding the data to the table, it adds the data beneath the existing table.

laptop_list.html

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="table-responsive-sm">
      <table class="table">
     {%for laptop in laptops%}
    <div class="table-responsive-sm">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{laptop.laptop_id}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.make}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.model}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.specification}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.warranty}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.condition}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.price}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </div>
      </table>
      {%endfor%}
      </div>

    </div>
```

models.py

```
class Laptop(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    specification = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    warranty = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default = None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def laptop_list(request):
    laptops = Laptop.objects.all()
    return render(request,'laptops/laptop_list.html',{'laptops':laptops})
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of errors here.

You can't have a `div` as a child of a table element. You should remove the duplicate `table-responsive-sm` div inside the table.

Also, the table should only have a single `tbody` element. The tbody should be outside the for loop.

So:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive-sm">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        {% for laptop in laptops %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{laptop.laptop_id}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.make}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.model}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.specification}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.warranty}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.condition}}</td>
            <td>{{laptop.price}}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thank you. It's the little ones that get you, I guess.